# Magento: additional category filter

Tags: magento, search, filter, layered-navigation

I a have a specific case of products search in Magento. On category page I would need to search only products that are deliverable for customer's zip code.

I didn't find a solution with Magento attributes (as it will work with many fields and calculations).

So basically I would like to create a special filter (additional block to standard layered navigation) to show only products that appear in result of SQL query.

Example: customer goes in category -> puts ZIP code in textbox -> MySQL query is executed to return SKUs available for the ZIP code -> category gets filtered to show only these products returned by SQL.

So just to simplify - I need a static block with button with function to hide all articles where SKU not in (x,y,z).

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: see http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/search_and_advanced_search/how_to_add_search_by_multiple_categories_to_advanced_search

Comment: Not sure, if it helps. I have gone though it and it's is easily applicable for advanced search. But how to make a filter in category? (additional filter to layered navigation)